# How to reset answers - HTML, Flask?

Tags: javascript, html, flask

how would I go about preventing a user from accessing submitted form data by resetting all of their answers. Say for example in a survey after they submitted and pressed the back button. Is there a way to reset the form?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
$(window).bind("pageshow", function() {
  var form = $('form'); 
  form[0].reset();
});
```

Also there is a way without using `JavaScript` is to use `<form autocomplete="off">` to prevent the browser from re-filling the form with the last values.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this without javascript is to turn off the autocomplete attribute of a form by :

```
<form autocomplete="off">
```

Another way to do this is to trigger a function which resets the form on page load.